# List Linked List reference

Tags: java, list, linked-list

How to get the data reference/index in Linked list?

e.g. if I have this linked list

```
java.util.List<Polygon> triangles = new LinkedList<Polygon>();

polygon triangle, selectedTriangle;
Point startDrag,endDrag,midPoint;
....

triangles.add( new Polygon(xs, ys,3));
```

e.g. How can I set the Polygon selectedTriangle as the same with one of the existing triangle in the linked array list?

EDITED:

```
java.util.List<Polygon> triangles = new LinkedList<Polygon>();
polygon triangle, selectedtriangle;
....

triangles.add( new Polygon(xs, ys,3)); 
.....

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
....
  startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());  
  endDrag   = startDrag;

  for (Polygon p : triangles) { 
    if (p.contains(startDrag)) {//inside triangle 

       //I dont know how to set the selectedTriangle as the same with existing triangle
       selectedTriangle = triangles.indexOf(p.contains(startDrag)); 
       break; //
    }
  }
.....

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `Polygon` overrides `equals` appropriately, you can use use:

```
int index = triangles.indexOf(desiredTriangle);
```

Note that using indexes with a linked list is relatively inefficient, as getting to any specific index means walking the whole list from the head to that index.

`LinkedList` doesn't offer an API to find the first equal element, but you could either use `indexOf` followed by `get` (requiring two passes) or write your own `findFirst` method like this:

```
public static <T> T findFirst(Iterable<? extends T> collection, T value)
{
    for (T t : collection)
    {
        if (t.equals(value))
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

(With suitable null checking if you need it.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you mean, I'd recommend using the get or indexOf methods.  You can see what they each do in the Java API: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Basically get takes in a number and returns the object at that index.  IndexOf takes in an object and returns the first index it is found at (or -1 if it is not found.)